# Closure may outlive the current function

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I am just starting to learn Rust. For this purpose I am rewriting my C++ project in Rust, but the biggest problems are lifetimes of closures and such.

I created a absolute minimal scenario of my problem seen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=14ed33c7fe2dddca6d7e60ef15d9f502&version=undefined) and below:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::cell::{RefCell, Cell};

struct Context {
    handler: RefCell<Option<Arc<Handler>>>,
}

impl Context {
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Context> {
        let context = Arc::new(Context{
            handler: RefCell::new(None),
        });

        let handler = Handler::new(context.clone());

        (*context.handler.borrow_mut()) = Some(handler);

        context
    }

    pub fn get_handler(&self) -> Arc<Handler> {
        self.handler.borrow().as_ref().unwrap().clone()
    }
}

struct Handler {
    context: Arc<Context>,

    clickables: RefCell<Vec<Arc<Clickable>>>,
}

impl Handler {
    pub fn new(context: Arc<Context>) -> Arc<Handler> {
        Arc::new(Handler{
            context: context,

            clickables: RefCell::new(Vec::new()),
        })
    }

    pub fn add_clickable(&self, clickable: Arc<Clickable>) {
        self.clickables.borrow_mut().push(clickable);
    }

    pub fn remove_clickable(&self, clickable: Arc<Clickable>) {
        // remove stuff ...
    }
}

struct Clickable {
    context: Arc<Context>,

    callback: RefCell<Option<Box<Fn()>>>,
}

impl Clickable {
    pub fn new(context: Arc<Context>) -> Arc<Clickable> {
        let clickable = Arc::new(Clickable{
            context: context.clone(),

            callback: RefCell::new(None),
        });

        context.get_handler().add_clickable(clickable.clone());

        clickable
    }

    pub fn remove(clickable: Arc<Clickable>) {
        clickable.context.get_handler().remove_clickable(clickable);
    }

    pub fn set_callback(&self, callback: Option<Box<Fn()>>) {
        (*self.callback.borrow_mut()) = callback;
    }

    pub fn click(&self) {
        match *self.callback.borrow() {
            Some(ref callback) => (callback)(),
            None => (),
        }
    }
}

struct Button {
    context: Arc<Context>,

    clickable: Arc<Clickable>,
}

impl Button {
    pub fn new(context: Arc<Context>) -> Arc<Button> {
        let clickable = Clickable::new(context.clone());

        let button = Arc::new(Button{
            context: context,

            clickable: clickable.clone(),
        });

        let tmp_callback = Box::new(|| {
            button.do_stuff();
        });
        clickable.set_callback(Some(tmp_callback));

        button
    }

    pub fn do_stuff(&self) {
        // doing crazy stuff
        let mut i = 0;

        for j in 0..100 {
            i = j*i;
        }
    }

    pub fn click(&self) {
        self.clickable.click();
    }
}

impl Drop for Button {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        Clickable::remove(self.clickable.clone());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let context = Context::new();

    let button = Button::new(context.clone());

    button.click();
}
```

I just don't know how to pass references in closures.

Another ugly thing is that my `Handler` and my `Context` need each other. Is there a nicer way to to create this dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going off your initial code

```
pub fn new(context: Arc<Context>) -> Arc<Button> {
    let clickable = Clickable::new(context.clone());

    let button = Arc::new(Button{
        context: context,

        clickable: clickable.clone(),
    });

    let tmp_callback = Box::new(|| {
        button.do_stuff();
    });
    clickable.set_callback(Some(tmp_callback));

    button
}
```

First off, let's note the error you're getting

```
    error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `button`, which is owned by the current function
   --> src/main.rs:101:37
    |
101 |         let tmp_callback = Box::new(|| {
    |                                     ^^ may outlive borrowed value `button`
102 |             button.do_stuff();
    |             ------ `button` is borrowed here
    |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `button` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
    |         let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
```

Noting the `help` block at the bottom, you need to use a `move` closure, because when the `new` function ends, the `button` variable on the stack will go out of scope. The only way to avoid that is to move ownership of it to the callback itself. Thus you'd change

```
let tmp_callback = Box::new(|| {
```

to

```
let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
```

Now, you'd get a second error:

```
    error[E0382]: use of moved value: `button`
   --> src/main.rs:107:9
    |
102 |         let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
    |                                     ------- value moved (into closure) here
...
107 |         button
    |         ^^^^^^ value used here after move
    |
    = note: move occurs because `button` has type `std::sync::Arc<Button>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

And the error here may be a little clearer. You're trying to move ownership of the `button` value into the callback closure, but you *also* use it inside the body of the `new` function when you return it, and you can't have two different things trying to own the value.

The solution to that is hopefully what you'd guess. You have to make a copy that you *can* take ownership of. You'll want to then change

```
let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
    button.do_stuff();
```

to

```
let button_clone = button.clone();
let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
    button_clone.do_stuff();
```

Now you've created a new `Button` object, and returned an `Arc` for the object itself, while also giving ownership of a second `Arc` to the callback itself.

#### Update

Given your comment, there is indeed an issue here of cyclic dependencies, since your `Clickable` object holds ownership of a reference to `Button`, while `Button` holds ownership of a reference to `Clickable`. The easiest way to fix this here would be to update that code a third time, from

```
let button_clone = button.clone();
let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
    button_clone.do_stuff();
```

to

```
let button_weak = Arc::downgrade(&button);
let tmp_callback = Box::new(move || {
    if let Some(button) = button_weak.upgrade() {
        button.do_stuff();
    }
});
```

so the `Clickable` will only hold a weak reference to the `Button`, and if the `Button` is no longer referenced, the callback will be a no-op.

You'd also probably want to consider making `clickables` a list of `Weak` references instead of strong references, so you can remove items from it when the item they reference is removed.

Comment: Yea, thats a solution i also came up with. Is there another way like ensuring that clickable inside button is cleaned up when button is going to be dropped, with lifetimes?
Anyways thanks for your effort!

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Besides my callbacks are now monsters, because I have up to 4 Arc's where I have to do the same as with button.

Comment: You could also consider making `Clickable` a trait, then implementing that trait for `Button` and such, then you'd register that instead.