# Specifying static lifetime of value in `main` so callback can borrow

Tags: rust

I have a variable that I am using to keep track of state which is updated by a handler closure. Something like the following:

```
fn main() {
    let val = 1;
    add_handler(|| val += 1);
    println!("{}", val);
}
```

The `add_handler` function is declared in another library and has the type

```
fn add_handler<F>(listener: F) where F: FnMut() + 'static
```

When I try to compile this, I get an error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `val`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     add_handler(|| val += 1);
  |                    ^^ --- `val` is borrowed here
  |                    |
  |                    may outlive borrowed value `val`
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `val` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
  |
3 |     add_handler(move || val += 1);
  |                 ^^^^^^^
```

Because `val` is declared in `main` I know it will live for the entire length of the program, but the compiler apparently doesn't know this, and I can't move `val` into the closure because I need to use it later.

This is similar to ["error: closure may outlive the current function" but it will not outlive it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651279/error-closure-may-outlive-the-current-function-but-it-will-not-outlive-it) but I can't get rid of the `'static` lifetime in the definition of `add_handler` because I don't control the definition.

This is not a duplicate of [Closure may outlive the current function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45745415/155423) because I can't move `val` into the closure.

I could make `val` a global atomic as per [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791532/how-do-i-create-a-global-mutable-singleton), but it seems like there should a cleaner more idiomatic way to tell the compiler that `val` will live long enough.

How do I do this?

Comment: *I know it will live for the entire length of the program* — It actually **won't**, which is why you get that error. The Rust `main` function exits *before* the OS `main` function does. Threads can and do continue running after the Rust `main` exits. This doesn't even cover the detail of destruction order of multiple variables in the same scope.

Comment: @Shepmaster That question does seem to include all of the salient points of this one. I'm fine with this being marked as a duplicate.